# extracting HOG features from .mat files and usage of "fitcecoc"

Tags: matlab

```
CS=[16,16];
traindb='D:\matprog\matfiles\trainfiles';
filePattern=fullfile(traindb, '*.mat');
matFiles = dir(filePattern);
for i = 1:length(matFiles)
      baseFileName = fullfile(traindb, matFiles(i).name);
      ref_files{i} = load(baseFileName);
      trainingfeatures(i,:)=extractHogfeatures(ref_files,'cellsize',CS);
end
traininglabels=traindb.Labels;

classifier=fitcecoc(trainingfeatures,traininglabels);
```

I have '.mat files' for different objects and I want to extract HOG features from the mat files, and I want to apply those features on "fitcecoc" SVM one vs one classifier. I have written a code but giving the error like this:
ERROR:
Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
how to give labels and is it correct way to follow?

Comment: I’m sure the error message also tells you exactly where this error happens. My guess it is at `traindb.Labels`, since `traindb` is a string, not a struct. But it could have happened earlier, inside `extractHogfeatures` because your first input there is a cell array, not an image.